# Magento2: Adding CMS Pages to menu with URL Rewrites

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, cms-pages

Following the magento1.x method for adding cms pages to the menu doesn't seem to work for magento2.x

At present I activate the autogenerated url for my homepage/home category which works - changing the url from `homepage.html` to `catalog/category/view/id/19`

I then create a custom url rewrite to change `catalog/category/view/id/19` to `home` which fails

Is this a bug, or has the method changed for adding cms pages to the main menu?

Answer (score 1):

Following

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

It's going to add new field in Admin Category Page

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect/blob/master/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="redirect_url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Redirect to another URL</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Core File as below

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect/blob/master/etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="redirect_url"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

It works for Me :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76767)

Comment: Noted. Will update